# Product of two series and its iterated sum

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement true?

> If $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i= A$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} b_j=B$ then
>    $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}
>  b_j\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_ib_j=
>  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_ib_j=AB$.

Note that $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}
 b_j\right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}
 b_j\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the double sum $$ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ib_j$$ is $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ib_j\right) $$ and we can write the inner sum as $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i b_j = b_j\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i = b_jA.$$ So $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ib_j = \sum_{j=1}^\infty Ab_j = A\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j = AB $$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the example:

$$A=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}\cdots= 1; $$
$$B=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^i}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}\cdots =\frac12.$$

Then:

$$\color{blue}{AB=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}
 b_j\right)=}$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}\cdots\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}\cdots\right)=$$

$$\frac12\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}\cdots\right)+\frac{1}{2^2}\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}\cdots\right)+\frac{1}{2^3}\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}\cdots\right)+\cdots=$$

$$\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_ib_j.}$$

$$\color{blue}{AB=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}
 b_j\right)=}$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}\cdots\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}\cdots\right)=$$

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}\cdots\right)\frac13+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}\cdots\right)\frac{1}{3^2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}\cdots\right)\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots=$$
$$
 \color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_ib_j.}$$